# Improve UX of a wide HTML table (using Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-table

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">List of meaningless things</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 table-responsive">
      <table id="course_groups" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Created at</th>
            <th>1
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>2
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="2">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>4
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="4">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>8
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="8">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>16
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="16">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>32
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="32">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>64
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="64">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>128
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="128">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>256
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="256">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>512
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="512">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>1024
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="1024">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>2048
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="2048">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>4096
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="4096">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>8192
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="8192">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>16384
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="16384">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>32768
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="32768">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>65536
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="65536">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>131072
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="131072">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>262144
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="262144">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>524288
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="524288">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>1048576
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="1048576">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>2097152
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="2097152">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>4194304
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="4194304">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>8388608
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="8388608">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>16777216
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="16777216">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>33554432
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="33554432">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>67108864
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="67108864">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>134217728
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="134217728">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>268435456
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="268435456">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>536870912
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="536870912">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
            <th>1073741824
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="1073741824">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" />
              </a>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Bongo</td>
            <td>5th August 2016 17:47</td>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bingo</td>
            <td>5th August 2016 17:47</td>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>No</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a very wide bootstrap table (see code snippet above).

I'd like to make the following changes:

1. Fix the width for all columns to be identical to the width of the longest header (currently each column gets progressively longer)
2. Continue to have horizontal scrolling, but partial columns should not be shown.

Is there a way to segment the columns so that they can be scrolled *n* columns at a time? I've seen some wide tables which have a control like the one below. Ideally, I'd like to avoid adding another JS dependency (e.g. Material) to my project.

[image: Scrollable buttons]

Also, is this a good way to show the table on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jumpScroll function to create scroll points and tie them to your UI with onClick events.

```
function jumpScroll() {
  window.scroll(100,0); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
}
```